# Susy 2 IE8 Fallback

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy

I need to add support for IE8 and possible previous versions using Susy 2 but there is very limited documentation that described how to do this.

I know in Susy 1 there was a lt-ie9 fallback tag to use against breakpoint declarations but that doesn't seem to work for Susy 2.

Is there any documentation for IE8 support or other way this can be achieved?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+8 Other than that, keep in mind that no one using IE8 is doing so on a smart phone! If you're doing "mobile first" development, than you'll need to add in a IE8 only sheet that uses desktop sizes as default.

Answer (score 2):

Susy doesn't exactly "support" specific browsers — since that would be determined feature-by-feature. I think media-queries are the only place you may need a fallback for IE8, and fallback options still exist for that. You can find [all the docs inline](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#breakpoint) with other information about media handling. We have some basic media-query tools built in, and additional support for the Breakpoint plugin. The built-in mixin is now called `susy-breakpoint()` and accepts a `$no-query` argument for managing your fallback.